# Regex - Match number range with no numbers around it

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind, digit

So I have something like this:

> \b(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6])\b

Which works fine for only matching numbers 1-36.  But I might get something like S36, which won't get matched.  I can't assume a clean word boundary on either side of the number.

I'd like to have it so it'll match 1-36 with anything except other numbers on either side.

I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't:

> (?<=\D)(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6])(?=\D)

It's supposed to be a positive look-behind at the start to make sure there is anything but digits preceding the number and a positive look-ahead after the number to make sure the same is true following it.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What regex engine? Lookbehind and even lookahead are not supported by all flavours.

Comment: I'm doing this in .NET, but testing it with the free software, Expresso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your engine doesn't support lookbehind/lookahead, then you can still just match the whole thing including the non-digits and pick the capture you're interested in.

```
(?:^|[^1-9])(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6])(?:$|[^1-9])
```

Your result would be in capture 1 in this example (the "outer" matches are in non-capturing groups).

Note that with .NET, you do have full support for lookbehind and lookahead, so that the following should work:

```
(?<![0-9])(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6])(?![0-9])
```

This uses negative lookaround instead of positive lookaround. Otherwise, numbers that are at the beginning or end of the string will not match because a non-numeric character is required where there is no character, leading to a non-match.

Comment: I just did a small edit to add the braces back into it, otherwise it will not work in all cases. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [^0-9] at the beginning and the end and then get the number by looking at the appropriate captured group ( second in this case ):

```
(^|[^0-9])(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6])($|[^0-9])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In terms of not matching numbers on either side, this is doing exactly what I want - but it is also matching non-digits.  So if I put in the string S36, it matches S36, and not just 36...

Comment: @dustmouse. _"and then get the number by looking at the appropriate captured group ( second in this case )"_. Javascript example: `'S36'.replace(/(^|[^0-9])(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-6])($|[^0-9])/, '$2')` The second captured group is the `$2`, so the result is `36`.